# Full calendar gets rendered in scrambled state inside react-bootstrap

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fullcalendar, react-bootstrap

I have following component on my page:

```
events = [{ title: "today's event", date: new Date() }];
<FullCalendar
                    height="auto"
                    contentHeight="auto"
                    defaultView="dayGridMonth"
                    plugins={[dayGridPlugin]}
                    events={this.events}
                />
```

When it is inside react-bootstrap accordion, it gets rendered in some scrambled state:

[image]

If I click previous / next button, then it gets correctly rendered. Also if I zoom in / zoom out, then also it gets rendered correctly.

I am able to imitate this in [this codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-calendar-forked-b5ge6n?file=/src/App.js):

[image: fullcalendar]

Accordion 1 is initially rendered in collapsed state. If you expand it, you will get exact same render as my first screenshot. Also note that if you zoom in or out in codesandbox webpage or click next or previous webpage, it renders correctly!

Why is this so?

PS:

I am using

```
"bootstrap": "^4.6.0",
"@fullcalendar/daygrid": "^5.11.3",
"@fullcalendar/react": "^5.11.2",
"react": "^17.0.1",
"react-bootstrap": "^1.4.3",
```

Comment: you'd need to [render](https://fullcalendar.io/docs/render) the calendar each time the according section containing it is opened, I think

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can  trigger a resize when opening the **two accordions** to prevent this behavior. you can do it by adding an `onClick` event  :

```
onClick={() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"))}
```

**change :**

```
<Accordion.Toggle
            as={Card.Header}
            eventKey="0"
          >
```

**and  :**

```
<Accordion.Toggle
            as={Card.Header}
            eventKey="1"
          >
```

**to :**

```
<Accordion.Toggle
            as={Card.Header}
            eventKey="0"
            onClick={() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"))}
          >
```

**and  :**

```
<Accordion.Toggle
            as={Card.Header}
            eventKey="1"
            onClick={() => window.dispatchEvent(new Event("resize"))}
          >
```

this is a demo in [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/basic-calendar-forked-lu16qg?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: So, what we are doing here? Programatically doing what zoom in and zoom out does?

Comment: In your code the  calendar it's not  rendered when the first time the component render .  I guess that's what make it render not properly . But it will renders correctly if it is called after the page is loaded, you can do it  by treggring resize in  the window.   Actually it should not behave like this  I guess it's a  bug you can report it 
in the  official githup repo of **react calendar**